# Custom MaxmindDB (geoip2) with Private IPs

Tags: perl, geoip, maxmind, geoip2

How to create a custom Maxmind database with PRIVATE IPs address.

I need something like this [Customizing Maxmind DB](https://github.com/threatstream/mhn/wiki/Customizing-Maxmind-IP-Geo-DB-for-Internal-Networks).

I tried to following this [Building Your Own MMDB Database for Fun and Profit](https://blog.maxmind.com/2015/09/29/building-your-own-mmdb-database-for-fun-and-profit/) . So I changed the PERL script to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use MaxMind::DB::Writer::Tree;
use Net::Works::Network;

my $filename = 'users.mmdb';

# Your top level data structure will always be a map (hash).  The MMDB format
# is strongly typed.  Describe your data types here.
# See https://metacpan.org/pod/MaxMind::DB::Writer::Tree#DATA-TYPES


my %types = (
    latitude => 'uint32',
    longitude     => 'uint32',
    city         => 'utf8_string',
    country     => 'utf_string',
);

my $tree = MaxMind::DB::Writer::Tree->new(

    # "database_type" is some arbitrary string describing the database.  At
    # MaxMind we use strings like 'GeoIP2-City', 'GeoIP2-Country', etc.
    database_type => 'My-IP-Data',

    # "description" is a hashref where the keys are language names and the
    # values are descriptions of the database in that language.
    description =>
        { en => 'My database of IP data', fr => q{Mon Data d'IP}, },

    # "ip_version" can be either 4 or 6
    ip_version => 4,

    # add a callback to validate data going in to the database
    map_key_type_callback => sub { $types{ $_[0] } },

    # "record_size" is the record size in bits.  Either 24, 28 or 32.
    record_size => 24,
);

my %address_for_employee = (
    '10.1.0.0/16' => {
          latitude => -12.9608,
        longitude      => 40.5078,
        city         => 'Maputo',
    country         => 'Mozambique',
    },
    '10.2.0.0/16' => {
        latitude => -25.0519,
        longitude      => 33.6442,
        city         => 'Gaza',
    country         => 'Mozambique',
    },
);

for my $address ( keys %address_for_employee ) {

    # Create one network and insert it into our database
    my $network = Net::Works::Network->new_from_string( string => $address );

    $tree->insert_network( $network, $address_for_employee{$address} );
}

# Write the database to disk.
open my $fh, '>:raw', $filename;
$tree->write_tree( $fh );
close $fh;

say "$filename has now been created";
```

But no luck. 
Now Im getting the following error : 
**Iteration is not currently allowed in trees with no nodes. Record type: empty at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/MaxMind/DB/Writer/Tree.pm line 292.**

Can anybody help me creating a GEOIP2 DB with private ip address?

Answer (score 2):

This is becuse the ip that your inputted is a private ip address.
you can solve it by editing the file:

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/MaxMind/DB/Writer/Tree.pm, line 307
307  my @reserved_4 = qw(
 308         0.0.0.0/8
 309         10.0.0.0/8
 310         100.64.0.0/10
 311         127.0.0.0/8
 312         169.254.0.0/16
 313         172.16.0.0/12
 314         192.0.0.0/29
 315         192.0.2.0/24
 316         192.88.99.0/24
 317         192.168.0.0/16
 318         198.18.0.0/15
 319         198.51.100.0/24
 320         203.0.113.0/24
 321         224.0.0.0/4
 322         240.0.0.0/4
 323     );
```

This is all the private ip address. remove somethings so that it works!
for example:
I remove "10.0.0.0/8", and execute the command: `perl examples/01-getting-started.pl` again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do what your said but unfortunately it does not work. I'm getting the following error now . 
Can't locate object method "_encode_utf_string" via package "MaxMind::DB::Writer::Serializer" at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/MaxMind/DB/Writer/Serializer.pm line 211.

Answer (score 2):

I used the **remove_reserved_networks** parameter in the constructor.

```
my $tree = MaxMind::DB::Writer::Tree->new(

# "database_type" is some arbitrary string describing the database.  At
# MaxMind we use strings like 'GeoIP2-City', 'GeoIP2-Country', etc.
database_type => 'GeoIP2-City',

# "description" is a hashref where the keys are language names and the
# values are descriptions of the database in that language.
description =>
    { en => 'IP-Ranges', de => q{IP-Bereiche}, },

# "ip_version" can be either 4 or 6
ip_version => 4,

# add a callback to validate data going in to the database
map_key_type_callback => sub { $types{ $_[0] } },

# "record_size" is the record size in bits.  Either 24, 28 or 32.
record_size => 24,

remove_reserved_networks => 0,
);
```